# MYSQL optimise left join with sub-query in large dataset (query taking way too long)

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a large dataset, and I have to do 3 joins, one of which is a sub-query.
I chose to use a subquery instead of WHERE (IN or FIND_IN_SET) so that I don't lose values in my left, or base table. I need all of the data in the left column. Overall, I'm matching 11 million values with 900,000 values, so I expect this to take long, but it took ~20 seconds on a set of 200.

The engine is innoDB, each table has a primary key (IDvar).

I use the sub-query because I have to many values that I need to select from (`val1, val2,..., val100`) and I want to avoid using the 'AND' command with a clause for every 'val'.

The query I am using is:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM table1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.var IN(val1, val2,..., val100)) AS t
        USING (IDvar)
    LEFT JOIN table3 
        USING (IDvar);
```

Comment: There is no `IDvar` in your subquery. I guess that is a mere typo in the example. Can you please correct it?

Comment: Ok, you were right, I fixed IDvar in the SELECT command, and FROM in the subquery.

Comment: No. There must be no `USING` after `FROM`. I'm referring to `LEFT JOIN (SELECT table2.var ...) USING (IDvar)`. The subquery only selects a column called `var` so you cannot join it on `IDvar`.

Comment: Ahhh, yes I see what you mean. I didn't post my original code (that works, but is super slow) with the variables so that instead I would present a MWE. I really hope this is enough to solve the problem.

Comment: It is rather uncommon by the way to join three tables on the same field. Usually this leads to a semi cross join. An example: Say you have departments, department rooms, and employees in the department. The join on department ID only would lead to a cross join of rooms and employees per department (John/room1, John/room2, Jane/room1, Jane/room2), which are not directly related.

Comment: What you think of this example: PersonID is joined across these tables (well the tables contain information named in the table title): Demographics, CT scans, Cancer Diagnosis, Date of Death. Effectively, the patient will have multiple CT scans (1:M join), which is the main join issue (subquery; I have many other services other than CT scans that I don't want to join), then he/she may have a cancer diagnosis, and may have a death. It is ok if the cancer diagnosis and death dates are found in each row for that person. I assume that this is a case which joining on the same field is appropriate?

Comment: It's up to you whether you find this result okay or not. I just wanted to point out it might be undesired. Date of death is a one time thing, but maybe your data model allows for multiple cancer diagnosises per person. Then a person diagnosed with cancer in 2000 and then again in 2015 may have had ten CTs from 2000 till 2004 and five CTs from 2015 till now. One might expect a result of 10 + 5 = 15 rows, but when only joining by person ID you'd get 2 (diagnosises) x 15 (CTs) = 30 rows instead.

Comment: Sometimes such results may be desired, other times they might indicate a flaw and the join would be extended somehow to include the time span, and other times still the programmer may decide to run two separate joins instead.

Comment: Your thoughts are appreciated. I totally see what you mean. I have one cancer diagnosis (the first diagnosis only), multiple CT scans, then one date of death, So I think this should be logical. based on joining to the same IDvar.

Answer (score 2):

The query looks fine to me. You'd want the following indexes:

```
create index idx_t1 on table1(idvar);
create index idx_t2 on table2(var, idvar);
create index idx_t3 on table3(idvar);
```

(Maybe it's just the second one that's missing.)

Comment: Right right, since table 1 and table 3 already have indexes (within primary keys), but I need to create an index for the table 2 subquery? I think this may be the solution.

Comment: That's the idea. Just try it. As you mention the primary keys: Does the pk only consist of `idvar` or are these composite keys consisting of multiple columns? If the latter, make sure that `idvar` is their first column. If it isn't, they are of no use for the query and you should add above mentioned indexes.

Answer (score 0):

May I clarify why you do not use `ON` statement?

In general, when I do joins, I do the following

```
SELECT * 
    FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON table1.common_var = table2.common_var
                JOIN table3 ON table1.common_var2 = table3.common_var2
    WHERE ...;
```

so that there is no need to load the whole huge table.

If there is a need to get every possible combination of the two table, we can get the two table separately and programatically get the combinations.

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
SELECT * FROM table2;
... the rest in another program ...
```

Comment: I don't use the ON statement as the primary key, and the foreign key are named the same thing, so I am told, that it is exactly the same as using the ON statement.

Comment: @user2444133: That is correct. The only difference is that with `ON a.x = b.x` both `a.x` and `b.x` exist in your result columns, whereas with `USING` there is only one `x`.

Comment: So does that mean that the program is more efficient using the 'ON a.x = b.x' style of JOIN? Will I gain computational efficiency?

Comment: @NicolasSmoll I am just not sure because it is the first time I see `USING`. I hope this does not confuse you

Answer (score 0):

Won't this do the same task?  And possibly be more efficient?

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
FROM      table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2  USING (IDvar)
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3  USING (IDvar)
WHERE t2.var IN(val1, val2,..., val100);
```

Indexes needed:

```
t2:  (IDvar, var)  -- in this order
t3:  (IDvar)
```

No index on `t1` will be used.

Having `LEFT` or not having it -- there is a big difference in this query.

Comment: This is what I started with. The problem with this query is because of the where clause. Using the where clause ends up subsetting the data in table 1. Effectively, only the values in table 1 that match the table 2 "IN" clause are represented. I need all the values in table 1 to be present. It seems to me that the "WHERE" clause is the problem, which is why I seem to need the subquery.